# Flutter: Is there a way for me to allow a user to select an image from their gallery and store it's path/url in a varable?

Tags: flutter

I'm working on an app in Flutter using Dart and Android Studio.
I want the user to be able to select an image from their gallery and add it to their feed, like a blog post per se.
I know there's image picker but need to do it without any additional packages or dependencies. Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Then you'd have to write your own equivalent implementation of image picker.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to use a package and dependency oriented framework such as Flutter without any packages or other dependencies? And even more specific when it comes to image_picker which is provided by flutter.dev ? That is basically wanting to use Flutter without Flutter...